# What do users who don't have my app installed see on the Google Play Store during a 'Staged Rollout'?

Tags: android, google-play

Let's say I want to release an update to my app but I only want to target 1% of users.

If new users visit the app's page on Google Play during a staged rollout, will they all see the brand new version targeted at 1% of existing app installs, or will they see the old version?

I appreciate this is a fairly basic question for Stack Overflow, but would appreciate any advice as this is suddenly very relevant for an upcoming update to my app.